# Running this function works but sends me back to the main view, why?

Tags: arrays, function, swiftui

I created the below code so i can update and save the information of the user but when i run the code it send me back to the main view and the function is used about ~2 views in (hope that make sense). Now, I know what line(s) of code are causing it to return to the main view but its the only way i can get it up to update the userInfoArray. When i comment out userInfoArray[index].name = name, it will not work. I tried the last code below (the one with specificUser variable), but it was not saving the information so i was not able to see the updated information in the other view.

```
func saveUpdatedUserInfo(index: Array<UserModel>.Index, name: String, amount: String) {
       
        
        usersInfoArray[index].name = name
        usersInfoArray[index].amount = amount

        try? save()
    }
```

the Function is used within a button view

```
 Button("Save") {
                       if let specificUser = dataViewModel
                            .usersInfoArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == self.id}){
                            dataViewModel.saveUpdatedUserInfo(index: specificUser,
                                                              name: userName,
                                                              amount: givenAmount)
                            print(specificUser)
                        }
```

Also, forgive me if this post looks weird, its my first time posting.

```
func saveUpdatedUserInfo(index: Array<UserModel>.Index, name: String, amount: String) {
        print(index)
        var specificUser = usersInfoArray[index]
        specificUser.name =  name
        specificUser.amount = amount
        
        try? save()
    }
```